# Microsoft Ajax Control Toolkit: client side error: null or undefined reference

Tags: javascript, ajax

Using the `Combobox` control of the Microsoft Ajax Control Toolkit,  I get some client side exceptions.

The debugger points me to this specific line of code:

```
text = this._optionListItems[this._highlightedIndex].text;
```

and the error message is:

> No se puede obtener la propiedad 'text' de referencia nula o sin definir

which roughly translates to

> Cannot get the property 'text' because of a null or undefined reference

also, a watch for the expression gives me that

```
this._optionListItems[this._highlightedIndex]
```

evaluates to undefined.

I'm OK with this, as I really need the functionality of the Combobox.
But I really need a way to prevent IE debugger to activate and stop execution of the page.

Is there a way to catch the error/exception and dismiss it?

Comment: +1 that's a very well written question, I don't know the answer but I'm sure someone can understand and help

Comment: Unfortunately, no one did...